How to fetch the ATH (all-time-high) for a token?
I'm looking for an API or even an explanation of a method to fetch the all-time-high price for a token on Solana.

one way would be to scrape the coingecko page of that token, but a major problem with that is coingecko's registry doesn't have all the tokens on solana but it doesn't have most of the major coins with high trade frequency

You can't fetch this on-chain directly, you will need some third-party indexer for this. Fortunately most popular indexers support an API for fetching historical price data, so I'd suggest using any of the following:

Coingecko: https://docs.coingecko.com/reference/coins-id-history
Birdeye: https://docs.birdeye.so/reference/get_defi-history-price
Coinmarketcap: https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV2CryptocurrencyQuotesLatest


Thanks, I might go ahead a build the on-chain alternative by parsing txn history and looking at the rate of which tokens are being swapped for but that seems very ineffecient
